# How do I hide a menu item with an <li> tag in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have a traditional menu that us based on this convention

```
<ul>
<li><xp:link>menu link 1</xp:menulink></li>
<li><xp:menulink>menu link 2</xp:menulink></li>
</ul>
```

I want to selectively render the menu link 2 based on some logic.
I can render the `<xp:link>` fine but as the `<li>` is a HTML tag rather than an XPages Tag       the rendering cannot be controlled.

I noticed that there is a tagName property for `<xp:text>` but not for `<xp:link>`.
see : http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=4EB7314545EE0C19852578CB0066CE4C

What is the easiest way to manage this without using repeats etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used xp:span in the past and it has worked fine.

```
    <xp:span>
       <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}]]></xp:this.rendered>
       <li>YOUR TEXT HERE</li>
    </xp:span>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also wrap the entire `<li>...</li>` tag in an `<xp:panel>` tag that has a rendered script on it. Don't give the xp:panel an ID and no extra code is sent to the browser.

If you are using the Extlib or UP1 then you can also use the `<xe:listcontainer>` tag. It renders each direct child entry as a list item so you would end up with code similar to..

```
<xe:listcontainer>
  <xp:link> ... </xp:link>
  <xp:link rendered="renderscript"> ... </xp:link>
  <xp:link> ... </xp:link>
</xe:listcontainer>
```

In this case there is no need for you to add the `<ul>` or `<li>` tags in the code, the ExtLib will look after that for you.

Comment: Thanks, the UP1 idea looks good. The idea of using so many panels seems very "expensive"

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the LI tag, use a panel and set the tagName to "li" (new since 8.5.3):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <xp:link>menu link 1</xp:link>
    </li>
    <xp:panel
        rendered="#{test == true}"
        tagName="li">
        <xp:link>menu link 2</xp:link>
    </xp:panel>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<ul>
    <li>Static item 1</li>
    <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1" tagName="li" rendered="false">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:'<a href="http://XPages.info">menu link 2</a>'}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
    <li>Static item 3</li>
</ul>
```

You can of course compute the rendered tag on xp:text.

Answer (score 0):

If your not worried about whether or not the code shows you can always just change the class on the li systematically using ssjs

```
<ul>
<li class="#{javascript:return myclassname;}"><xp:link>menu link 1</xp:menulink></li>
<li><xp:menulink>menu link 2</xp:menulink></li>
</ul>
```