# server side js on pure CSS

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, server-side

now i'm workin on dropdown menu using PURE CSS method on Xpages lotus notes 8.5.2

I'm followin the tutorials [from this link](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu)

but I got errors when i put these codes inside li tag

```
< li>< this.rendered>< ![CDATA[#{javascript:x=sessionScope.get("level");x!="MR"}]]>< /this.rendered>< a href="#">Report</a> < /li>
```

Can someone help me with these? I googled and couldn't find the right method yet.

thanks

Comment: In adition to Per's answer: think of pure HTML tags as of "passthrough HTML". So they are not JSF components, therefore you can not use common component properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<li>` is not an XPages control and you can therefore not use this.rendered.

Instead you can use the computed text control and set it to render as `<li>`. Here's an example:

```
<xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1" tagName="li">
    <this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:x=sessionScope.get("level");x!="MR"}]]>< /this.rendered>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:'<a href="#">Report</a>'}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210709/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-with-an-li-tag-in-xpages) contain other examples of similar approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary HTML taggs don't have any properties like rendered. only xpages taggs has properties. So that is the first thing you need to look into.